# How to remove Contextual Search 'This Site:' from dropdown box of target result page

Tags: search-results, search-scope, enterprise-search

The target search results page is */_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx*.  In Site Actions >Search Setting> selected *Show, do not include contextual scopes* for Site collection Search Dropdown Mode. It is not displaying contextual scope in the search box but in target results page, it adds the contextual scope *'This Site: SiteTitle'*

Env: SharePoint Server 2010

Pls let me know if anyone has solution for it.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1):

jack,

in order to use *custom scopes* instead of *contextual scopes* in result page we will replace *Default Search Result Page* with *Search Site Result Page*.

The following steps should be accomplished:

A. [Create **site** or **site collection** for Search using one of the following site templates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

- Enterprise Search Center
- Basic Search Center

B. Enable to use **custom scopes** and specify Search site location in Search Settings page as shown below

[image]

C. Specify for the [Search Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.searchboxex.aspx) web part **Target Search Results Page Url**. It should points to result page in search site as shown below

[image]

Hope this helps,
Vadim